# python choose random word from list

Tags: python, string, list, random, combinations

I am working on a project where I want a program that makes a string containing 5 random words from a list. The list contains 5 words and I want all possible combinations where only one word from the list can be used once per string.

```
import time
import random

lista = ["w1", "w2", "w3", "Vickpix", "siplse"]

database = []

count = 0

while True:
    nu = random.choice(lista) + random.choice(lista) + random.choice(lista) + random.choice(lista) + random.choice(lista)
    if nu in database:
        pass
    else:
        count += 1
        print(count)
        database.insert(1, nu)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate all permutations of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-do-i-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

[random.sample doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html?highlight=random%20sample#random.sample)

```
import time
import random

lista = ["w1", "w2", "w3", "Vickpix", "siplse"]

database = []

count = 0

while True:
    nu = random.sample(lista, 5)
    if nu in database:
        pass
    else:
        count += 1
        print(count)
        database.insert(1, nu)
```

Comment: the infinite loop will take a long time to get all of the permutations.  If you want to get all permutations do not use a random technique.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list